# Window.location HTML page is not loading jpg images

Tags: javascript, html

I am using window.location however my images are not loading in that page for some reason? I have checked my file path and all is fine. My images are working fine in my main index.html file so I'm assuming it has something to do with my new file(window.location). The console is saying "ERR image not found."

I believe I am missing something. I'm quite new to the window.location feature can anyone help?

JS:

```
        <script>

 document.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (document.readyState === "interactive") {
              initApplication();
          }
      }

      var eyeColor = null;
      function selectMenu1(value){
        eyeColor = value;
      }

      var skinTone = null;
      function selectMenu2(value){
        skinTone = value;
      }

      function validate()   {
        if (eyeColor && skinTone){
          alert(`You selected ${eyeColor} eye colour and ${skinTone} skin tone.`);
          //////////////////////////

          // extra conditions below

          //////////////////////////
          if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="fair"){
            window.location = "brown/brown_fair.html";
          } else if (eyeColor=="brown" && skinTone=="tan"){
            alert("You should have w/e colour hair...");
          }
        }
        else if (!eyeColor){
          alert("Please pick an eye colour");
        }
        else if (!skinTone){
          alert("Please pick a skin tone");
        }
      }

      function initApplication(){
        //setup dropdown menu selection events
        Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu")).forEach((menu,idx)=>{
          const menuCallbackName = menu.attributes.onchange.value;
          const fetchedCallback = window[menuCallbackName] || null;

          if (fetchedCallback){
            Array.from(menu.children).forEach((child)=>{
              const callbackValue = child.attributes.data ? child.attributes.data.value : null;
              if (callbackValue) child.onclick = () => fetchedCallback(callbackValue);
            });
          } else console.error(`No callback function named ${menuCallbackName} for menu ${idx}`);

        });
      }


    </script>
```

HTML in window.location file

```
        <div class="jumbotron text-center">
  <h1 class="display-4" style="font-size: 2.5rem">Best Hair Color for: <br> 
  </h1>
  <p class="lead">Brown Eyes & Fair Skin</p>
  <hr class="my-4">

 <img src="img/ash_brown.jpg">
 <img src="img/medium_brown.jpg">
 <img src="img/caramel_mix.jpg">

  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

This is the structure of my project:

[image]

Comment: What's the full path for your image files:  <img src="img/caramel_mix.jpg">

Comment: Hi there, I believe my full file path would be "img/ash_brown.jpg". My hair images are in the "img" folder.  I have attached an image. The img folder is in the HairApp folder.

Comment: have you tried this path:<img src="/img/ash_brown.jpg">?

Comment: Hi Hooman, I just tried that and no success.

Comment: try with ../img/ash_brown.jpg. hope it will work

Comment: Yay! That was it! Thanks Jay!

Answer (score 0):

You are using a [relative path](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp) in your HTML:

```
 <img src="img/ash_brown.jpg">
 <img src="img/medium_brown.jpg">
 <img src="img/caramel_mix.jpg">
```

So, your browser will look for 'ash_brown.jpg' in the current location... and as shown in your project structure, that is not where your images are located.

If you change your image location relative to the root of your website, the should work:

```
 <img src="/img/ash_brown.jpg">
 <img src="/img/medium_brown.jpg">
 <img src="/img/caramel_mix.jpg">
```

*Considering img folder is in the root folder of your website, it should work.*